# Return first/second occurrence

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a way to grab/ capture the second occurrence of the number (only the number) next to {"$oid":

I was able to capture the first one But having trouble catching the second/ third occurrence.

this is the regex that i used:
https://regex101.com/r/6cSXi8/1

```
"(?<="\$oid": ").*?[^"},]*"
```

**Example of input:**

```
[{"_id": {"$oid": "5f9ecf8ca9bec5549493ba7d"}, "policy_name": "aaa", "is_mobile": false,, {"_id": {"$oid": "6090fead53bc363849fce989"}, "policy_name": "bbb", "is_mobile": true, {"_id": {"$oid": "619cf729ea016d1e3336e903"}, "policy_name": "ccc", "is_mobile": false}]
```

In addition, i was also trying to figure out how can i match "is_mobile" : true to the number at the second occurance. meaning a regex that will return the second number (next to {"$oid":) by searching for "is_mobile" : true

i'm using Java to send the regex

would appreciate your assistance.

Comment: Using a regular expression to parse JSON will eventually fail.  You really should use a proper JSON parser.

Answer (score 0):

You say you use Java, so you must choose 'Java' at regex101! That will tell you to escape all double quotes (`"`).

I have changed your regex to use the '`Global`' flag and changed the look ahead:

```
"(?<=\"\$oid\": \")[^\"]+(?=\"[^$]+\"is_mobile\": true)"
```

The look behind is the same. I then changed the match to match any character not being a double quote `"`.

I then add a look ahead to look for:

`"` the double quote ending the match

`[^$]+` Any character (one or more) not being `$` - this ensures that the look ahead does not look ahead to another item (which might have a true value), but stays in the same item.

`\"is_mobile\": true` look ahead for the `true`value.

The '`Global`' will match ALL occurences only if it's followed by a `ìs_mobile: true`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How do I get the second number without using the "is_mobile": true? I would like to get the third (nth occurance).

Comment: If you want all matches, just set the `global` flag, without the look ahead.

Comment: Can you provide a regex  example using regex link that I provided to get only the second number?

Comment: The regex in my answer above only gives you the second number. You MUST use the global flag.

Answer (score 0):

Other Alternatives:

See regex in context and testbench:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "[{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"5f9ecf8ca9bec5549493ba7d\"}, " +
            "\"policy_name\": \"aaa\", \"is_mobile\": false," +
            ", {\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"6090fead53bc363849fce989\"}, " +
            "\"policy_name\": \"bbb\", \"is_mobile\": true, " +
            "{\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"619cf729ea016d1e3336e903\"}, " +
            "\"policy_name\": \"ccc\", \"is_mobile\": false}]";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"\\$oid\":\\s+\"(\\S+)\".*?\"is_mobile\":\\s+(true|false)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);

    //Alternative 1:
    System.out.println("Alternative 1:");
    while(matcher.find()) {
        if(matcher.group(2).equals("true")) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }

    //Alternative 2:
    Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("\"\\$oid\":\\s\"(\\S+)\".*is_mobile\":\\s(true|false)");
    List<String> isMobileTrueOidList = Arrays.asList(input.split("(?<=is_mobile\":\\s(true|false))")).stream()
            .map(pattern2::matcher)
            .filter(Matcher::find)
            .filter(matcher2 -> matcher2.group(2).equals("true"))
            .map(matcher2 -> matcher2.group(1))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    System.out.println("\nAlternative 2:");
    isMobileTrueOidList.forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Output:

```
Alternative 1:
6090fead53bc363849fce989

Alternative 2:
6090fead53bc363849fce989
```